# is it bad to control non-input data with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I made a form using react-hook-form. In my form, there are multiple input and there is a one part that choose a word and pass array with specific id. and it is a two dimensional array. and there are more complex methods..

I use react-hook-form, I control it by using `getValues() and setValue()`. but I think it isn't a normal way(I think there are no dif with useState, setState)
but I want to submit that data with other input field data because other field is controlled by input.

In my opinion, using zustand(I'm using zustand) to control data and pass data when submit event occurs, is it better way ? or using previous ?